# php isset() not working correctly with filter_var()

Tags: php

```php
$id = $_GET["id"];
// $id = filter_var($_GET["id"],   FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

if (isset($id)) {
   echo "has id";
} else {
   echo "no id"
}
```

This is a simplified version of my code. When I use the `filter_var` to sanitize `GET`, it's always echoing "has id".

With simple `$_GET["id"]`:

```
index.php        => no id
index.php?id=123 => has id
```

With `filter_var`:

```
index.php        => has id (not correct)
index.php?id=123 => has id
```

Comment: In both cases, you assign values to `$id` - why do you expect that `isset` works different?

Comment: isn't `id` null when I go to `index.php` without parameters? @NicoHaase

Comment: `filter_var` will return an empty string on empty input

Comment: @NicoHaase This is literally the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose you should use `filter_input()`. It will both fix undefined index warning (which you are getting on first 2 lines) and return `null` if the input variable is not set (`filter_var()` returns an empty string in this case):

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, u need realize why u get true statement on `isset` after `filter_var`. Quick check in documentation says `filter_var` return

> Returns the filtered data, or false if the filter fails.

So for you its return `false` ;)

Now you need check dcumentation for `isset`

> Determine if a variable is declared and is different than null

So `false` is corect ;)

Now you need to search other solution or rework your solution ;)
For me Sharky give you one of best solution.

Answer (score 0):

As documentation state here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php for `filter_var()`

```
value
Value to filter. Note that scalar values are converted to string internally before they are filtered.
```

And here https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting

```
A bool true value is converted to the string "1". bool false is converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and forth between bool and string values.
```

so `isset()` will retrive empty string and won't complain.

You can try this:

```
if ($_GET["id"]) {
   echo "has id";
} else {
   echo "no id"
}
```